# Difference between the joint probability $P(x_2,t_2;x_1,t_1)$ and the conditional probability $P(x_2,t_2|x_1,t_1)$

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

What is the difference between the ***joint probability*** $P(x_2,t_2;x_1,t_1)$ and the ***conditional probability***  $P(x_2,t_2|x_1,t_1)$ where $x_1,x_2$ are two values from the sample space of a random variable $X$? Here, $t_1$ and $t_2(>t_1)$ represent time.

It will be helpful to get an answer that will explain the meaning of these two probabilities in the example I wrote.

Answer (score 1):

Joint probability describes the probability that two (or more) events both occur:  What is the (joint) probability that I find the next car that passes is both red and a four-door model?

Conditional probability describes the probability of an event *given that another event has occurred*.  What is the (conditional) probability that *given the next car is in fact red* that it is also a four-door model?